# Remote access kibana

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a db elasticsearch. I still access this database using kibana via http://localhost:5601 address. Now I want to share the link so that others can access my db, what do I need to fix?

```
I tried:
   sudo ufw allow 5601/tcp
   server.host: <my ip>
   network.host: <my ip>
but have error:
     elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-14 15:51:48 +07; 18s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 5083 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=78)
   Main PID: 5083 (code=exited, status=78)
        CPU: 25.605s

Thg 3 14 15:51:38 congthanhcomputer systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd-entrypoint[5083]: ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines be>
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd-entrypoint[5083]: bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; a>
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd-entrypoint[5083]: ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Thg 3 14 15:51:48 congthanhcomputer systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 25.605s CPU time.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Answer (score 0):

kibana.yml

> **server.host: 0.0.0.0**

First make sure your Kibana is working.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5601/api/task_manager/_health"
```

Update your Kibana.yml and update the server.host to reach your kibana from the outside of the server. And use the ip address of your server to reach your kibana.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html